# How to create vb.net object class from json file (or xml file)

Tags: xml, json, vb.net

I'm wondering how to create a objet class from json file or xml file ?

example :

I get this json file from webservice :

```
{"nid":"3798","vid":"3788","type":"contact","language":"fr","title":"G","uid":"1","status":"1","created":"1374598689","changed":"1374598689","comment":"1","promote":"0","sticky":"0","tnid":"0","translate":"0"}
```

I would like to create a class like :

```
Public Class Card
  Public nid As Integer
  Public vid As Integer
  Public type As String
  Public language As String
  Public title As String
  .
  .
  .
End Class
```

NB :

- My question is not how to serialize / deserialize json objet in vb.net ?
- My xml file doesn't have XSD that why is more difficult
- My code is written in VB.Net not in C#. I found many website which convert json to c# (http://json2csharp.com/), but nothing json to vb.net

If I have no choice I will create manually my classes ... :-(

Thank in advance for your help

Eric

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you're talking about XML and JSON files, I recommend you to install [Web Tools 2012.2](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20122-release-notes-rtw).

This adds a nice new feature to Visual Studio:

> Paste JSON as a .NET class. Using this Special Paste command to paste JSON into a C# or VB.NET code file, and Visual Studio will automatically generate .NET classes inferred from the JSON.

[image]

If you have e.g.

```
{"nid":"3798","vid":"3788","type":"contact","language":"fr","title":"G","uid":"1","status":"1","created":"1374598689","changed":"1374598689","comment":"1","promote":"0","sticky":"0","tnid":"0","translate":"0"}
```

in your clipboard, it will generate this class for you:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property nid As String
    Public Property vid As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property language As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property uid As String
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property created As String
    Public Property changed As String
    Public Property comment As String
    Public Property promote As String
    Public Property sticky As String
    Public Property tnid As String
    Public Property translate As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Amazing how many sites I've looked up about this and you're the first to mention that the solution is right here in my own kitchen!

Comment: You are a genius

Answer (score 2):

You can convert json to csharp using (http://json2csharp.com/) and then convert csharp code to vb.net using http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/. For deserialization you can use  Newtonsoft.Json. Your deserialization code will be :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of YourClass)(<JSON String>)
```

Comment: It should work too, but I'd rather Dominic Kexel' solution ;-)