# How to extract "status" value only from a String of json object got from lextlocal SMS Api

Tags: vb.net, json.net

how to extract `status` value only from a String of `json` object got from

> lextlocal SMS Api=>

```
{"balance":5,"batch_id":332134398,"cost":1,"num_messages":1,"message":{"num_parts":1,"sender":"TXTLCL","content":"Hello world"},"receipt_url":"","custom":"","messages":[{"id":"1264163821","recipient":918481946255}],"status":"success"}
```

through `VB.net` and using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only care about a single property `"status"` that is at the root level in your JSON, you can use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) to extract it:

```
Dim status = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, New With {.status = "" }).status
```

Alternatively, if you needed to extract one or two properties that are nested within the JSON, you could parse to a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) and extract the desired values using [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm), e.g.:

```
Dim token = JToken.Parse(json)

' Extract status and cast the value to a string
Dim status = CType(token.SelectToken("status"), String)

' Extract first message recipient and cast the value to a string
Dim firstRecipient = CType(token.SelectToken("messages[0].recipient"), String)
```

Sample [working .Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NHpzpo).

Finally, you could define explicit types into which to deserialize your JSON using a code-generation tool such as http://jsonutils.com/  or [Paste JSON as Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529988) and remove unwanted properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
JSON.net https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

and then you can do it like this:

Dim o = Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
Console.WriteLine(o("status"))