# Unable to Parse odd JSON Object with JsonConvert

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json.net

Unable to parse the following with JsonConvert...

```
{
    "ico": {
        "upcoming": [
            {
                "name": "Crowdwiz",
                "image": "https://icowatchlist.com/logos/crowdwiz.png",
                "description": "CrowdWiz Bringing the future of investment into your hands",
                "website_link": "https://api.icowatchlist.com/public/v1/url/crowdwiz",
                "icowatchlist_url": "https://icowatchlist.com/ico/crowdwiz",
                "start_time": "2017-10-24 12:00:00",
                "end_time": "2017-11-07 12:00:00",
                "timezone": "UTC+0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Publica",
                "image": "https://icowatchlist.com/logos/publica.png",
                "description": "Blockchain revolution for the publishing economy",
                "website_link": "https://api.icowatchlist.com/public/v1/url/publica",
                "icowatchlist_url": "https://icowatchlist.com/ico/publica",
                "start_time": "2017-10-25 00:00:00",
                "end_time": "2017-11-15 00:00:00",
                "timezone": "UTC+3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Typically I would create a class; but can't figure out how with this structure. This is the code I have (vb.net, but C# solution is fine).  Any help would be much appreciated...

```
Try
    url = "https://api.icowatchlist.com/public/v1/upcoming"

    Dim theurl As New Uri(url)

    Using webClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        json = webClient.DownloadString(theurl)
        Dim dataWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MarketWrapper)(json)

        For Each jobject In dataWrapper.ico

            Dim s As String = jobject.name
        Next
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    some_msg = ex.Message
End Try
```

The error I get from asp.net...

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ping60+DataWrapper]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'ico.upcoming', line 1, position 19.

Class that I have, tried other options, but still no go...

```
Class MarketWrapper
    Property ico As List(Of DataWrapper)
End Class

Class DataWrapper
    Property name As String
    Property image As String
    Property description As Single
    Property website_link As String
    Property icowatchlist_url As String
    Property start_time As String
    Property end_time As String
    Property timezone As String
End Class
```

@dbc solution works. added this to my code to loop through ico list...

```
For Each jobject In dataWrapper.ico.upcoming
   Dim s As String = jobject.name
Next
```

Comment: @dbc fixed.  you can see the format at the UTL https://api.icowatchlist.com/public/v1/upcoming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code-generation tool such as https://jsonutils.com/ or [Paste JSON as Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529988/3744182) to automatically generate VB.NET classes from your JSON.  Tools like these don't handle everything correctly (e.g. dictionaries) but in this case jsonutils works and generates the following:

```
Public Class Upcoming
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property image As String
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property website_link As String
    Public Property icowatchlist_url As String
    Public Property start_time As String
    Public Property end_time As String
    Public Property timezone As String
End Class

Public Class Ico
    Public Property upcoming As List(Of Upcoming)
End Class

Public Class MarketWrapper
    Public Property ico As Ico
End Class
```

Notes:

- You need an extra level of class `Ico` between your root object `MarketWrapper` and the `List(Of Upcoming)` to capture the `upcoming` property.
- `description` must be a `String` not a `Single`.
- I did change the auto-generated `Public Property upcoming As Upcoming()` to be of type `List(Of Upcoming)`.  Code-generation tools such as this one often favor arrays over lists.

Sample [VB.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pweKGA).