# How to parse through following ZOHO People JSON string using VB.NET?

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the following code and JSON format as a response to Zoho People API call from VB.NET. The requirement is to parse through the values and build insert SQL queries.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "507258000002665141": [
        {
          "CreatedTime": "1574925427929",
          "ZP_Leave_File_Upload": "",
          "Employee_ID": "2042",
          "AddedTime": "28-Nov-2019 11:17:07",
          "Leavetype.ID": "507258000000169001",
          "From": "27-Nov-2019",
          "Unit": "Hour",
          "ModifiedBy": "7151",
          "ApprovalStatus": "Approved",
          "Daystaken": "16.0",
          "Reasonforleave": "",
          "ModifiedBy.ID": "507258000000145005",
          "TeamEmailID": "",
          "Leavetype": "Annual Leave",
          "ModifiedTime": "1574925427930",
          "ApprovalTime": "28-Nov-2019 11:17 AM",
          "Zoho_ID": 507258000002665141,
          "AddedBy.ID": "507258000000145005",
          "To": "23-Dec-2019",
          "AddedBy": "7151",
          "Employee_ID.ID": "507258000000148879",
          "DateOfRequest": "28-Nov-2019",
          "ZP_Leave_File_Upload_downloadUrl": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "507258000002652283": [
        {
          "CreatedTime": "1574922096199",
          ...........
        }
      ]
    }
    ],
  "message": "Data fetched successfully",
  "uri": "/api/forms/P_ApplyLeave/getRecords",
  "status": 0
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: You could deserialize this JSON as a `List(Of Dictionary(Of string, DataTable))` (since it doesn't look like the last three fields - `message` etc. - are required). If you need (as probable) the object keys (`507258000002665141` etc.) as PKs, add the keys in a loop to a new Column before submitting the DataTable. Otherwise, you can use a custom JsonConverter (but I doubt it's really needed here).

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to realize is that this structure:

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "507258000002665141":[
            {
               // Some standard properties

            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "507258000002652283":[
            {
               // Some standard properties
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is an array of objects, each of which has a single property with a variable property name whose value is an array of objects with a standard schema.  This can be represented with a

```
<JsonProperty("result")>
Public Property Result As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Result)))
```

With that realization, you can use a code-generation tool such as  https://www.jsonutils.com/ to generate some initial VB.NET classes and then make the necessary fixes to the `Result` property and any other tweaks as required, as most code-generation tools will not recognize such a structure.  This is the result:

```
Public Class RootObject
    <JsonProperty("result")>
    Public Property Result As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Result)))

    <JsonProperty("message")>
    Public Property Message As String

    <JsonProperty("uri")>
    Public Property Uri As String

    <JsonProperty("status")>
    Public Property Status As Integer
End Class

Public Class Result
    <JsonProperty("CreatedTime")>
    Public Property CreatedTime As String

    <JsonProperty("ZP_Leave_File_Upload")>
    Public Property ZPLeaveFileUpload As String

    <JsonProperty("Employee_ID")>
    Public Property EmployeeID As String

    <JsonProperty("AddedTime")>
    Public Property AddedTime As String

    <JsonProperty("Leavetype.ID")>
    Public Property LeavetypeID As String

    <JsonProperty("From")>
    Public Property From As String

    <JsonProperty("Unit")>
    Public Property Unit As String

    <JsonProperty("ModifiedBy")>
    Public Property ModifiedBy As String

    <JsonProperty("ApprovalStatus")>
    Public Property ApprovalStatus As String

    <JsonProperty("Daystaken")>
    Public Property Daystaken As String

    <JsonProperty("Reasonforleave")>
    Public Property Reasonforleave As String

    <JsonProperty("ModifiedBy.ID")>
    Public Property ModifiedByID As String

    <JsonProperty("TeamEmailID")>
    Public Property TeamEmailID As String

    <JsonProperty("Leavetype")>
    Public Property Leavetype As String

    <JsonProperty("ModifiedTime")>
    Public Property ModifiedTime As String

    <JsonProperty("ApprovalTime")>
    Public Property ApprovalTime As String

    <JsonProperty("Zoho_ID")>
    Public Property ZohoID As Long

    <JsonProperty("AddedBy.ID")>
    Public Property AddedByID As String

    <JsonProperty("To")>
    Public Property [To] As String

    <JsonProperty("AddedBy")>
    Public Property AddedBy As String

    <JsonProperty("Employee_ID.ID")>
    Public Property EmployeeIDID As String

    <JsonProperty("DateOfRequest")>
    Public Property DateOfRequest As String

    <JsonProperty("ZP_Leave_File_Upload_downloadUrl")>
    Public Property ZPLeaveFileUploadDownloadUrl As String
End Class
```

Notes:

- I used the tool https://www.jsonutils.com/ to generate the classes above, checking `[x] VB.Net` and `[x] Pascal Case`.  After, I fixed the class names and the `Result` property, which rendered an intermediate level of auto-generated class unnecessary.

  `Public Property To As String` also had to be fixed to `Public Property [To] As String`.

  I also replaced all arrays with lists.
- While there aren't as many options for auto-generating VB.NET classes from JSON as there are for c#, see *[How to create vb.net object class from json file (or xml file)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22528884/3744182)* for some additional options.
- You may want to change some of the date and time properties to be of type `DateTime`, e.g.:

  ```
  <JsonProperty("AddedTime")>
  Public Property AddedTime As DateTime
  ```
- The attribute [`<JsonProperty(string name)>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) is from the serializer [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net).  If you are using a different serializer you will need to use a different attribute to specify serialized property names, such as [`<JsonPropertyName(string name>]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute) for `System.Text.Json`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I1uHzO).