# Need a help to deserialized nested json response

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

with the web api getting following response, want help to deserialize following json response in vb.net.

```
 {
"data": {
    "getReport": {
        "report_date": "April 20, 2020",
        "report_date_iso": "2020-04-20",
        "links": {
            "__typename": "Links",
            "proportions_diagram": null
        },
        "results": {
            "shape_and_cutting_style": "Emerald Cut",               
            "data": {
                "shape": {
                    "shape_category": "F"                   
                },
                "girdle": null,
                "inscription_graphics": []
            }
        },
        "quota": {
            "remaining": 4971
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Where exactly are you stuck? Have you tried [Paste JSON As Classes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/) which is available for both c# and vb.net and will automatically generate a model you can use to deserialize the sample JSON?  See [How to create vb.net object class from json file (or xml file)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22528884/3744182).

Comment: i have the classes with me generated through  https://jsonutils.com/ . not getting output with deserialized. Dim Result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Example)(rawresp)

Comment: Then can you share a [mcve] showing the classes you tried?  Maybe https://jsonutils.com/ doesn't generate a correct model.

Comment: you are right . jsonutils.com didn't generated correct model. generated through VS now its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfect for me on .NET Core 3.1.

To test it:

1. In Visual Studio 2019, create a winform in .NET Core 3.1.  Be sure it has the NuGet package for Newtonsoft.JSON.
2. Add a button called `btnJsonConvTest`, and a textbox called `txtJSONinput`.
3. Add a new class file to the project - name doesn't matter.  Delete standard content from the file.
4. Select and copy your JSON.  In Visual Studio, click Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes.  This will create the class structure you see below.
5. Add the bits of code from below.  Note that I gave my class the name `JSONTestObject`.
6. Run your program, paste your JSON test string into the text box, and click the button.

**Code:**

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Button click event:

```
private void btnJsonConvTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JSONTestObject testobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONTestObject>(txtJSONinput.Text);
    String res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testobj);
    MessageBox.Show(res);
}
```

And the class that VS created for us:

```
public class JSONTestObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Getreport getReport { get; set; }
}

public class Getreport
{
    public string report_date { get; set; }
    public string report_date_iso { get; set; }
    public Links links { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
    public Quota quota { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public string __typename { get; set; }
    public object proportions_diagram { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public string shape_and_cutting_style { get; set; }
    public Data1 data { get; set; }
}

public class Data1
{
    public Shape shape { get; set; }
    public object girdle { get; set; }
    public object[] inscription_graphics { get; set; }
}

public class Shape
{
    public string shape_category { get; set; }
}

public class Quota
{
    public int remaining { get; set; }
}
```

When I test it, I get the same JSON string back out as went into it, thus proving that both the serialization and deserialization methods correctly move data in and out of the class properties.